# dryer vent . venting into the crawl space

Tags: vent, dryer

Just bought a house no basement have a crawl space the dryer vent discharges into the crawl space . The furnace is also near by. ? Good or bad .

Comment: Someone's downvote was a little harsh, in my opinion. Anyway, the linked question will tell you everything you need. (Hint: bad.)